# What is the current halacha on internet filters?

Tags: halacha, internet

Is there a consensus concerning the neccessity and the level of internet filter (especially for man) when one has internet in his home ? Some of my friends that are orthodox jews and are serious about all halachot do not have an internet filter in their homes. Is it correct to say that a man who uses unfiltered internet violates the halacha, or is there room for arguing that when a person has sufficient self-control to avoid  improper websites (always or with very rare exceptions), he is not violating the halacha ?

Comment: Hi Yitzhak! It's great to have you learning with us! We have an existing question that should answer yours. The search feature can be a bit wonky sometimes so don't feel bad you couldn't find it

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yitzhak and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!